# How to use grid-row mixin

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm struggling with understanding how this mixin works. The example the documentation provides is...

```
@include grid-row($columns, $behavior, $width, $cf, $gutter) { */ what goes here???*/ }
```

This is what I have in my SCSS...

```
.custom_row {@include grid-row(20, nest, 1000, true, 15);}
```

What I'm trying to do is make a row that has 20 columns instead of the default 12.

The SCSS seems to compile fine but that mixin isn't outputting anything to my CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It would be great if Zurb's documentation would give an actual example on how to use these.

Here's what worked for me...

```
.custom_row {@include grid-row(20, 'nest', 1000, true, 15) {
    .custom_column {@include grid-column(4,10);}
}
```